# What is the alternate solution for Facebook's ShareLinkContent deprecated functions for Android?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In `Facebook` API for Android previously we were able to share url content with title, Imageurl, link and contentDescription like this way

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentTitle("Planning a trip to Dubai?")
    .setContentDescription("Make sure you visit unique attractions recommended by the local people!")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://justa128.github.io/dubai-tour-guide/landingpage/"))
    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/t/800/240/1*jZ3a6rYqrslI83KJFhdvFg.jpeg"))
    .build();
```

But right now the methods `setContentTitle`, `setContentDescription`, `setImageUrl` are deprecated. Is there any alternate solution to share content with url, imageurl, title and description?

`Facebook's` documentation of [ShareLinkContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareLinkContent) is not helpful.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: _“Is there any alternate solution to share content with url, imageurl, title and description?”_ - OG meta tags. Yes, only those. (Unless you share to a page, and that page has claimed ownership of the domain - only then can those values still be set/overwritten dynamically.)

Comment: @CBroe So there is no direct solution for this? How to share to FB using metatags?

Comment: _“How to share to FB using metatags”_ - by specifying only the URL.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setQuote("Any Description String") method of ShareContent.Builder to set the quote to display for your link.
Something like that

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
           .setQuote("Planning a trip to Dubai? \n Make sure you visit unique attractions recommended by the local people!")
           .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://justa128.github.io/dubai-tour guide/landingpage/"))
           .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

P.S.-> setTitle , setDescription and setImageUrl methods are deprecated now in Latest FacebookSDK so we can used setQuote for title and detailed description and setContentUrl for link.